# ReactJS: return an alert after fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make an api call

**report.tsx**

```
  if (buttonClick === 'pdf') {
        getReportPDF(params, sort);
   }
```

**report-reducer.ts**

```
export const getReportPDF = (search, sort) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(search) ? new URLSearchParams(search).toString() : null;
  const sorting = new URLSearchParams(sort) ? new URLSearchParams(sort).toString() : null;

  const requestUrl = `${apiUrlPDF}?${params}${Object.keys(sort).length > 0 ? '&' + sorting : ''}`;
 
  fetch(requestUrl).then(response => {
    response
      .blob()
      .then(blob => {
        if (blob.type === 'application/problem+json') {
          alert('Nothing');
        } else {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = url;
          a.download = 'report.pdf';
          a.click();
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error is ', error));
  });
};
```

Now my problem is: at the moment I'm using an alert directly in the reducer, but if I would show a different alert

( for example usign bootstrap:

```
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  A simple primary alert with <a href="#" class="alert-link">an example link</a>. Give it a click if you like.
</div>
```

)

in the report.tsx, how can I do? I should return something in  `if (blob.type === 'application/problem+json')`  ??

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a state in `report.tsx` that controls showing of alert:

```
const [isAlertShowing,setAlertShowing]=useState(false)
```

Now make `getReportPDF` take an extra callback parameter in case of success:

```
    export const getReportPDF = (search, sort, callback) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(search) ? new URLSearchParams(search).toString() : null;
  const sorting = new URLSearchParams(sort) ? new URLSearchParams(sort).toString() : null;

  const requestUrl = `${apiUrlPDF}?${params}${Object.keys(sort).length > 0 ? '&' + sorting : ''}`;
 
  fetch(requestUrl).then(response => {
    response
      .blob()
      .then(blob => {
        if (blob.type === 'application/problem+json') {
          callback() // invoke the callback here or anywhere else you that you want
        } else {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = url;
          a.download = 'report.pdf';
          a.click();
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error is ', error));
  });
};
```

Then pass a function as `callback`, that sets `isAlertShowing` to `true`

```
    const activateAlert=()=>setAlertShowing(true)

    if (buttonClick === 'pdf') {
        getReportPDF(params, sort, activateAlert);
   }
```

Finally, in render of the component, show the alert whenever `isAlertShowing` is `true`:

For example:

```
return (
   {isAlertShowing && <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" ....
```